# Where are examples for using SLDS Dueling Listbox?

Tags: lightning-design-system, lightning-duallistbox

In my components I want to use the Dueling-picklist from the LIGHTNING DESIGN SYSTEM. [On the website](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/dueling-picklist/) there is no example code but just this BETA note.

[image]

I need examples for the markup and how to add functionality to it. Did anyone implement this already?

Comment: "This is a prototype" means "this is likely to change before release, so you should not attempt to use it." That said, it's entirely possible to write your own...

Comment: I will NEVER write my own listbox again. Never ;-)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented this design twice - my second effort is much more performant and functional.

https://github.com/rapsacnz/DualSelect

Here's what it looks like:

[image: DualSelect gif]

You can:

- Drag from source to destination
- Drag from destination to source
- Dragging will attempt to put the item where you dropped it.
- Drag to reorder in any list
- Shift select several items in source or destination, then use the arrow buttons to move to either source or destination
- Highlight an item and use the up / down buttons to move up and down.

Comment: Nice. Great work!

Comment: Glad you like it. My next one is a lightning notes framework driven entirely by custom metadata - you define the notes you want to appear in metadata and configure where you want the notes to appear in lightning layout. It's nice because you can make different notes show up in different places all driven by the same metadata.

Comment: Great work. I hope the native Dueling Listbox Salesforce will release in Winter'18 as part of Lightning Base components will be as elegant as this one.

Comment: btw, here's the lwc version:  https://github.com/rapsacnz/OrderedListGroup

Answer (score 3):

I've found this example of another developer's implementation of a dueling picklist:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dueling-picklists-lightning-component-yogaraj-kv-1/

and the code for the example is at:

https://github.com/yogarajkv/DuelingPicklist_Lookup-Lightning/tree/master/aura